# How do I find what version of CKAN I am running

Tags: ckan

How can I find what version of CKAN I am running? Preferably programatically or via some machine readable way?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Older versions of CKAN had the version displayed on the footer of the page. Starting from CKAN 2.0, the version number is displayed in the source code with the following tag:

```
<meta name="generator" content="ckan 2.0.1" />
```

Or you can make this API call:

http://demo.ckan.org/api/util/status

```
{
ckan_version: "2.0.1",
site_url: "http://demo.ckan.org",
site_description: "Demo",
site_title: "CKAN Demo",
error_emails_to: "root",
locale_default: "en",
extensions: [
"stats",
"social",
"demo",
"datastore",
"datastorer",
"resource_proxy",
"recline_preview",
"json_preview",
"pdf_preview",
"repo_info",
"spatial_metadata",
"spatial_query",
"geojson_preview"
]
}
```

Comment: Note to others: you can see the tag referenced by going on the web UI, right clicking, select "Inspect" (or whatever takes you to the web dev console), expand the html header, and check the "meta" tags.

Answer (score 6):

In later versions (testing 2.8.3) it is {{url}}/api/3/action/status_show

Answer (score 0):

You can also rebuild ckan in the main directory inside the virtual environment in /src/ckan `python setup.py [develop | install]` The output will have the version number